# How to change text colors in Anaconda Powershell Console?

Tags: powershell, console, anaconda

I installed Anaconda 3 and opened a Powershell. By default the commands I type appear in (unreadable) yellow. I want all text I type and all text the shell displays to appear as black on the default (white) background.

I tried setting colors on the properties page (rt-click -> Colors) by setting screen text and popup text to black and screen/popup background to white but that appears to do absolutely nothing.

Comment: You can try the cmd prompt shell. Open Anaconda navigator, in that lauch cmd. Now you can change text color and background color by using color command. @Alex